# Howto add element inside form_widget

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I´m trying to apply bootstrap style to a symfony2 form.
I want to know how to add an html element inside a form_widget.

This is my code:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    <div>
        <span class="label label-primary">{{ form_label(form.username) }}</span>
        {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="label label-primary">{{ form_label(form.age) }}</span>
        {{ form_errors(form.age) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.age) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-default btn-mg'}}) }}
    </div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Specifically I wan to add a  element inside the save button:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
```

The only way I find to do this is creating a custom element modifying his appropiate class.

Comment: there is a package that adds twitter bootstrap to form elements. Take a look at http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way of doing this is customize an individual field theming in symfony forms http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field